# form data is not received

Tags: django, forms, twitter-bootstrap, post

I am using Django and Bootstrap on frontend to write a single profile editing module.

Plain form from Django is ugly, so I did some custimizing on the form. Here is the HTML form:

```
        <form actoin="{% url 'edit_profile' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="chineseName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input name="chinese_name" class="form-control" id="chineseName" placeholder="name" value="{{form.chinese_name.value}}">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="gender" class="col-sm-2 control-label">gender</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        {% if form.gender.value == "M" %}
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender1" value="M" checked> Male
                        {% else %}
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender2" value="M"> Male
                        {% endif %}
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        {% if form.gender.value == "F" %}
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender1" value="F" checked> Female
                        {% else %}
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender2" value="F"> Female
                        {% endif %}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="age" class="col-sm-2 control-label">age</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input name="age" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="年龄" value="{{form.age.value}}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">phone</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="phone" value="{{form.phone.value}}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-xs-12" id="confirm" style="display:none;">confirm</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Somehow request.POST is not receiving data from this form. When I switch this long HTML snippet into {{form}}, everything is fine.

So view function is correct. Is there anything wrong with this template file, especially the form part?

Comment: you have a typo in `actoin` attribute of form. Are you sure that POST data goes to needed url?

Comment: @valentjedi I corrected this and nothing changed. Since it is the default url this post goes to. I tried hard coded url yet still not working. I think this is something about HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the css in the form class, for example if you are using `ModelForm`:

```
self.fields['phone'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = self.fields['phone'].label
```

or if you are using `Form` :

```
phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'phone'))
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. Actually I printed request.POST, turned out that this is empty. I think there is nothing to do with Django. It's something about HTML

Answer (score 0):

Nothing looks out of order at first look. One way to debug further would be to instantiate the form and print it. Then compare everything, especially the `<form>` tag and `<input>` tags.